# GPS not working

Tags: android

What I am doing is trying to get a basic GPS working and can't figure out the problem (there is no errors coming up). When i run it on the emulator it crashes. I am using android 2.2

```
package Weather.app;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class WeatherAppActivity extends Activity{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
 private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters
 private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Milliseconds


protected LocationManager locationManager;
protected LocationListener MyLocationListener;
protected Button findButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    findButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findButton);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
              locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
              MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
              MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
              (LocationListener) this
            );



    findButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        showCurrentLocation();
                    }
    });  
}

    protected void showCurrentLocation() {

                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                if (location != null) {
                    String message = String.format(
                            "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                            location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
                    );
                    Toast.makeText(WeatherAppActivity.this, message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                final class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
                     @Override
                        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                             String message = String.format(
                                 "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                             location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
                              );
                              Toast.makeText(WeatherAppActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                     @Override
                        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
                              Toast.makeText(WeatherAppActivity.this, "Provider status changed",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                     @Override
                        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                            Toast.makeText(WeatherAppActivity.this,
                                  "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",
                                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                     @Override
                        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
                            Toast.makeText(WeatherAppActivity.this,
                                   "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",
                                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                          }

                }                           






}
```

}

This is also in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" />
```

I have updated this code as I have made a few changes

Comment: Post the logcat showing where the application crashes. With that we can help pinpoint exactly where it crashes and why

Comment: Where do you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`? Try it after `</application>`

Comment: Yes its is under </application> and all it shows in the logcat is E/AndroidRuntime(340):  ... 11 more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one example of working basic GPS activity:

```
 public class UseGpsActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

    }
  /* Class My Location Listener */

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double lati = loc.getLatitude();
        double longi = loc.getLongitude();

        String Text = "My current location is: " + "Latitud = " + lati + "Longitud = " + longi;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Gps Disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Gps Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless some code is missing in your post `MyLocationListener` (you should not user upper case identifiers for instance fields!) is not initialized when passing the reference (i.e. `null`) to `requestLocationUpdates()`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create another LocationListener, the statement

```
WeatherAppActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener
```

and the overriden methods

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
```

etc means you have one in your main class already, so get rid of the inner class MyLocationListener completely.

Put your Toast code etc inside the overriden listener methods in the main class.

Then in onCreate() have :

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
  locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
  MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
  MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
  this
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a tutorial on Android location services on my blog. I'm not sure of your specific error but you can look at the code to see if it helps you!

http://www.scotthelme.co.uk/blog/android-location-services/